# Can ROS2 run on macOS big sur 11.5.2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can ROS2 run on macOS big sur 11.5.2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388606/can-ros2-run-on-macos-big-sur-11.5.2?/) by [dsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/87191/dsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The last version to be mentioned explicitly in [REP 2000: ROS 2 Releases and Target Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#foxy-fitzroy-may-2020-may-2023) was Mojave, and I haven't heard of any work regarding porting to any newer versions.

That doesn't immediately mean it can't be built on newer versions of the OS of course.

See [macOS support in ROS 2 Galactic and beyond](https://discourse.ros.org/t/macos-support-in-ros-2-galactic-and-beyond/17891) on ROS Discourse for a recent(-ish) discussion about this, and the linked [ros2/ros2/issues/1148](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1148).

The last update to that issue states:

> Various issue, specifically related to Big Sur and/or Apple silicon (M1 cpu) break the build.

but that is the status as of 2021-06-02. Things may have changed in the meantime.

---

Edit: I forgot about the work of the RoboStack devs. See [RoboStack/ros-galactic](https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-galactic) and [RoboStack: Using ROS alongside the Conda and Jupyter Ecosystems on any Linux, macOS, Windows & ARM](https://discourse.ros.org/t/robostack-using-ros-alongside-the-conda-and-jupyter-ecosystems-on-any-linux-macos-windows-arm/20250). You're going to need Conda, but IIRC, you should be able to install (at least some parts of) ROS 2 Galactic on macOS that way.

Note: this is not equivalent to "official" support for macOS. But it's as good as it's going to get for now I believe.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0